# How to add a image display in rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave

I am using CarrierWave in rails to upload images for my food records. I already created a single column 'avatar' in food model and the uploading form in the  template view works well.

I want to add a display section for the image in the show.html.haml and display the image uploaded for the food record. How can I implement that?

What I do now in the show.html.haml is:

```
= link_to image_tag( 'picture.jpg'), @food_item.avatar.current_path
```

Answer (score 0):

```
= link_to @food_item.avatar.current_path do
  = image_tag(@food_item.avatar_url) if @food_item.avatar?
```